Vuetify Combobox text highlighting when using item slot
When using the item slot in the Vuetify Combobox, we lose the default search text highlighting.
Example
In Vue2 there was a way to pull that functionality from the parent as seen in this answer
Is there something similar for Vue3? I see the functionality I want in their source code, but I'd rather not duplicate that in my app.
